# How to insert character in all possible positions of a string?

Tags: delphi

I want to insert a char into every possible position of s string except start and end.
e.g.

```
abc
I want to have 
a-bc
ab-c
a-b-c
```

Below is my test, but not correct:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
start, i,j,k,position,loop: integer;
laststart,lastend:integer;
c,item,stem:string;
str, prefix:string;
begin
str:='abcd';
memo1.clear;
memo1.Lines.Add(str);
laststart:=0;
lastend:=memo1.lines.count-1;
position:=0;
prefix:='';
loop:=0;
while loop<=length(str)-1 do
  begin

    for j:= laststart to lastend do
    begin
    item:=memo1.lines[j];
        for k:=length(item) downto 1 do
        begin
            if item[k]='-' then
            begin
            position:=j;
            break;
            end;
         end;  //for k
   prefix:=copy(item,1,position);
   stem:=copy(item,position+1, length(item));

        for start:=1 to length(stem)-1 do
        begin
        c:=prefix+copy(stem,1,start)+'-'+
        copy(stem, start+1,length(stem));
        memo1.lines.add(c);
        end;
     end; //for j
    laststart:=lastend+1;
    lastend:=memo1.Lines.Count-1;
inc(loop);
end; //end while

end;
```

it outputs:

```
abcd
a-bcd
ab-cd
abc-d
a--bcd // not correct
a-b-cd
a-bc-d
ab--cd //incorrect
ab-c-d
abc--d  //incorrect
a--bc-d //incorrect
```

I feel the maximum possible breaks is lenth(str)-1, abc->most possible is insert 2 '-' (twice). Is this correct?

And are there other faster ways to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: To achieve this, I'd play with binary numbers... I'd increase it... if 0 no delimiter, if 1, add a delimiter...

Comment: @Whiler: That's exactly what I did below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
  N: integer;
  Marker: cardinal;
  MaxMarker: cardinal;
  Str: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  S := Edit1.Text;
  N := length(S);
  Marker := 0;
  MaxMarker := 1 shl (N - 1) - 1;

  Memo1.Clear;
  Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;

  for Marker := 0 to MaxMarker do
  begin
    Str := S[1];
    for i := 2 to N do
    begin
      if (Marker shr (N-i)) and 1 <> 0 then
        Str := Str + '-';
      Str := Str + S[i];
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Str);
  end;

  Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
end;
```

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, it works by using binary representation of numbers:

```
t e s t
 0 0 0
 0 0 1
 0 1 0
 0 1 1
 1 0 0
 1 0 1
 1 1 0
 1 1 1
```

Comment: would be interesting to do this without bit pattern tricks, for example for N greater than machine word size

Comment: @David: I suspect you need more lines then.

Comment: @Andreas No, recursive version has 3 lines only (between begin and end)

Comment: As Fermat says "this margin is too narrow to contain" :), so I'll give it in additional answer

Answer (score 9):

Recursive version.

```
  procedure InsertSymbols(s: string; c: Char; Position: Integer = 1);
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
    for i := Position to Length(s) - 1 do
      InsertSymbols(Copy(s, 1, i) + c + Copy(s, i + 1, Length(s) - i), c, i + 2);
  end;

begin
  InsertSymbols('Test', '-');
end;
```

Comment: +1 for ingenuity. In addition, this solution allows for far longer strings than my solution (although my solution can easily be slightly modified to allow for arbitrarily long strings).

Comment: String with 32 chars produces about 100 GB output, so application of any method to longer strings is more theoretical...

Comment: You are right. By the way, I wonder what application the OP is having in mind.

Comment: +1 too... my 2 cents: `procedure InsertSymbols(s: string; c: Char; Position: Integer = 1);`

Comment: @MBo, Thanks so much. A very flexible way, position can be customized.

Comment: @Warren What goal are you going to reach? Is effectiveness important?

Comment: @MBo, Thanks. I want to split a word into all possible forms that are segmented by a char so that I can find the possible whole word matches  or part matches of substrings that already are stored in a database. You mentioned above that length of word will determine efficiency. A wild guess is that ususal word might not exceed 32 in length. But your point really matters if I consider longer words though they are not that long. Then other ways would be better.

Comment: @Warren Probably, this problem might be solved by algorithmic means - dedicated data strucures, special algorithms for fuzzy matching (against for exhaustive search). But it seems beyond of the scope of this topic

Answer (score 1):

Why all the difficult solutions?
Just copy the string to a new one char by char, add hyphens in between, except for the last one.

Comment: This answer would be more impressive with some code doing just that.

Comment: Not for something as trivial as that

Answer (score 1):

I needed to separate a string to use as a serial number and here is the code:

```
Function GetDashedKey(Key: string): string
const
  PartSize = 7;
var
  Indx: Integer;
  dashedKey : string;
begin

  repeat
    if Trim(dashedKey)<>'' then
      dashedKey := dashedKey + ' - ';

    if Length(Key) < PartSize then
    begin
      dashedKey := dashedKey + Key;
      Key := '';
    end
    else
    begin
      dashedKey := dashedKey + Copy(Key, 1, PartSize);
      Key := Copy(Key, PartSize + 1, Length(Key)-1);
    end;
  until Trim(Key) = '';

  Result := dashedKey;
end;
```